# What are the differences between the different Rate Equations?

Tags: kinetics, rate-equation

I currently am about to finish general chem 2 so my knowledge is still basic.

There are different kinetics and rate equations and im not quite sure I know the differences.

1. Breaking rate of a reactant: ${\frac{\ce{-[R]}}{Δt}}$.

Formation rate of a product: ${\frac{\ce{[P]}}{Δt}}$

2. $v$ = $\ce{-\frac{1}{a}}\frac{\ce{d}\ce{[A]}}{\ce{d}t} 
   = \ce{-\frac{1}{b}}\frac{\ce{d}\ce{[B]}}{\ce{d}t}=
   \ce{\frac{1}{p}}\frac{\ce{d}\ce{[P]}}{\ce{d}t}
   =\ce{\frac{1}{q}}\frac{\ce{d}\ce{[Q]}}{\ce{d}t}$
3. Rate = ${k\ce{[A]}^\ce{{n}}} \ce{{[B]}^\ce{{m}}}$.....

If I remember and understand correctly, equations 1 and 2 are in regards to the initial concentration, so they're the rate at the beginning of a chemical reaction... I think..
If so, does that mean equation 3 is for any given point in time, just insert the concentration at given time?

Can anyone please explain what are the differences and when to use what?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 
// Optionally, here are formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: Note that, simplified, anything in italic is considered as a variable or scientific constant.  // For more details: [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: You should mention that your expressions are only valid in an equation written $\pu{a \mathrm{A} + b \mathrm{B} -> p \mathrm{P} + q \mathrm{Q}}$

Answer (score 1):

For reaction

$$\ce{a A + b B -> p P + q Q}\tag{1}$$

is

$$r_\textrm{A} = -  \frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{A}]}{\mathrm{d}t}\tag{2}$$ resp. $$r_\textrm{P} =   \frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{P}]}{\mathrm{d}t}\tag{3}$$
the consumption rate of the reactant $\ce{A}$, resp. the production rate of the product $\ce{P}$.

---

$$r = -\frac{1}{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[A]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{b}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[B]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{p}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[P]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{q}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[Q]}}{\mathrm{d}t} \\ = \frac{r_\textrm{A}}{a} = \frac{r_\textrm{B}}{b} = \frac{r_\textrm{P}}{p} = \frac{r_\textrm{Q}}{q}\tag{4}$$

is the reaction rate, being the absolute value of the reaction rate of any reactant or product, divided by the respective stoichiometric coefficient.

---

$$r = k[\ce{A}]^a[\ce{B}]^b\tag{5}$$

it the reaction rate expressed by the reaction kinetic constant and concentration of reactants. Note that this is true only for single step elementary reactions, otherwise things get complicated by reaction chains and loopbacks.

If there is equation $y = x$ and $y = z$, then $x = z$, because we can substitute $y$ in the latter by $x$ from the former.

Therefore:

$$r = -\frac{1}{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[\ce{A}]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = -\frac{1}{b}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[\ce{B}]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{p}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[\ce{P}]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{q}\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[\ce{Q}]}}{\mathrm{d}t} = k[\ce{A}]^a[\ce{B}]^b \tag{6}$$

---

You can determine

- the reaction rate from the reaction rates of reactants or products,
- the reaction rate from the concentrations of reactants or products,
- the reaction kinetic constant $k$ from both rates and concentrations.

Comment: Thanks, it was trivial mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much.
So just to make sure, the above equations are used to express the rate of a reaction by using different data, i.e.  stoichiometry or concentration for example.

So when im asked to calculate the initial rate, I can use equations 4 and 5, and when asked to calc concentrations at specific time, I can use equation 5 (or 4, but i'd need the difference in both time and concentration)

Thanks again!

Comment: It is like the equation z=x.y . If you know z, you know x.y.  If you know x and y, you know z. If you know z and ý, you know x.

Answer (score 0):

The second equation is the definition of reaction rate. The symbol used for rate sometimes is $v$, or it is written out as rate. The third equation is the rate law, telling us how the rate changes with concentration (at a given temperature).

The first set of equations is unfamiliar to me, and don't look like a rate as given.

Comment: the first ones are the average rates of breaking and forming of components.

So as Poutnik commented, are the reaction rate and rate law equal?

Comment: The quantities "rate" and $v$ are equal. The rate law is a different equation than the equation defining rate.